# Change image on click in custom listview Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

In my custom listview I want to change Image when the image is clicked. 
But currently when I click on Image, last row image is changed not the one on which I clicked.
My customAdapter classis below:

```
package com.zek.androidvoicechanger;

import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

    Context context;
    ImageView image ;


//  int[] Radio = { R.drawable.play, R.drawable.pause };

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Items> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        // ImageView imageView;

        TextView txtTitle;
//      ImageView img;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Items rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//          holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        //  holder.rdo = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        image.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "image clicked", 1000).show();
                if(position==0){
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
                AudioListner.playRecord(position);

            }
        });



    //holder.rdo.setTag(position);
//      holder.rdo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//
//          
//              
//          }
//      });

//      rdo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//
//              
//              if(position==0){
//                  rdo.indexOfChild(findViewById(isEnabled(position)));
//                  Toast.makeText(context, "image clicked", 1000).show();
//                  rdo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
//                  AudioListner.playRecord(position);
//                  
//              }
//              
//              
//              
//              if (rdo.isClickable()) {
//                  rdo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
//                  Toast.makeText(context, "image clicked", 1000).show();
//
//                  //Radio[1] = 1;
//                  AudioListner.playRecord(position);
//                  
//              } else {
//              //  rdo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
//                  Toast.makeText(context, "image not clicked", 1000).show();
//
//              }
////
//          }
//      });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have `ImageView image` which belongs to your adapter and you don't handle individual list items clicks. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapter based views like `ListView` recycles its views to save resources. During scrolls, ListView will recycle views that are no more visible. This post by Lucas is a great place to learn more about its working: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

So registering onClick in your `getView()` method might not be a very good idea. Instead use the [setOnItemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) method on your ListView.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you can do this:

**Edit**: Updated my code as per your comment.

```
mYourListView..setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item #" + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // here, "position" is the position of your item and "id" is your
            // item's id in your data set.

            // mLastClickedPosition is a member field of type long which 
            // stores the position of the most recently clicked item, 
            // initially set to -1
            if(mLastClickedPosition != -1){
                  // do something to pause the item in your list at this position
            }

            // next, update mLastClickedPosition
            mLastClickedPosition = position

            // find the image in your view and update it
            if(position==0){
                  ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.your_image);
                  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }

            // play audio
            AudioListner.playRecord(position);

        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you all of u guyz it was real helpful. it is working but i have one real problem that is i wana change image of each imageview in list it that is clicked and want rest all of them in previous state.. example play and pause .if i play one item it icon is changed to pause  icon and when i click other one it also changed in pause state what i what is one at a time to play and the rest in pause state..how can i handle that ..?

Comment: @zek, that's pretty easy to do. Simply use an extra member field to track the position of last clicked item. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

In your posted code you have `ImageView image` which belongs to your adapter, and therefore "global" to your list.

Instead, what you seem to want is to have `onClick` handler for each individual list item.

For this I recommend you to implement [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) for you listView,

or alternatively you could change your `onClick` code to something like :

```
    // set onClick for each img in the list
    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    });
```

and don't forget to initialize `holder.img` as it is currently commented out.

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to maintain the position of clicked row. You can do this by creating an array. Everytime you click on a row image, you can add this row's position into this array. Also use this arrray to populate your listview using if-else condition. I have aaded that in code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Items rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//          holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        //  holder.rdo = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        if(yourSelectedImageArray.contains(position)){

         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);//your clicked image
        }else{
        image.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());//your default image
        }
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        //image.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "image clicked", 1000).show();
                if(position==0){ //not sure about this logic..
                yourSelectedImageArray.add(position);//add the clicked position into an                       array.
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
                AudioListner.playRecord(position);

            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

also dont forget to remove position from this array when you click on any other row. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Maintaining a separate data structure for tracking clicked row items is not a very good approach.